# How to add View pager and recycler view under scroll view layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have `RecyclerView` and `ProgressBar` under `RelativeLayout`. `ProgressBar` shows in center until data loads in `RecyclerView`. I want to implement `ViewPager` on top and below it `RecyclerView` so that whole view can be scroll easily.

This is what I have done so far:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progress2"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/refresh">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycle"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Someone please let me know how can I make desired layout. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 0):

Try after changing `layout_width` & `layout_height` like following:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progress2"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/refresh">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/recycle"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```